# If statement never evaluates false when it should

Tags: powershell, if-statement

Another amateur issue with a script I am working on. I am having an issue with exiting my script and console from within an `If` statement.

I have tried `exit`, `exit()`, `$host.exit` and `[Environment]::Exit(1)` within my `Else` portion. No matter what the user input is, the if statement continues.

I feel like I am missing something very simple but I can't figure it out. I only want it to continue if the user enters "Y" or "y". Anything else I just want it to fail and close...

I have also called `$confirm` after the user input make sure it's capturing the correct letter, which is is.

Here is the portion of the script that is failing:

```
$confirm = Read-Host "Continue deletion? [Y/N]"

if ($confirm -eq "Y" -or "y") {
    for ($i = 0; $i -le 4; $i++) {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $path0, $path1 -Filter "$dval*"| 
        % { Write-Host 'Deleting' $_.FullName $dval; Remove-Item $_.FullName -Recurse }
        $dval++ } 

} else { [Environment]::Exit(1) }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following statement is not doing what you think its doing.

```
if ($confirm -eq "Y" -or "y")
```

The issue here is that there are two separate statements being tested here that you might not expect `$confirm -eq "Y"` and `"y"`. The latter would evaluate one its own as true since it is a non empty non null string.

Consider this lonely statement `[bool]"y"` which would return `True`.

So what you meant to write was `$confirm -eq "Y" -or $confirm -eq "y"`. However that is redundant [since `-eq` is case-insensitive by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6). So `$confirm -eq "Y"` would suffice on its own.

Additional reading would be about how [`about_Logical_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-6) work. It has some simple examples of how to chain multiple comparisons. To say the left hand side is evaluated independently of the right would be incorrect.

> The PowerShell logical operators evaluate only the statements required to determine the truth value of the statement. If the left operand in a statement that contains the and operator is FALSE, the right operand is not evaluated. If the left operand in a statement that contains the or statement is TRUE, the right operand is not evaluated.

With your code entering any letter or value has no effect since `-or "y"` is always true. Entering any non-y value with the updated answer would make `$confirm -eq "y"` return `False`

---

If there was a reason to evaluate multiple distinct possibilities you would be looking at `-contains` or `-in`. I will leave it to you to look further into those (to keep the tangents down)

```
$confirm -in "y","m","b"
```

Where Y=Yes, M=Maybe and B=Bagel

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! Followup.... So if it evaluates the lowercase y separately, and does so as true, which is fine. What is it doing if you enter n? Because as it sits now, entering any letter it evaluates as true.

Comment: @eknack87 With your code entering any letter or value has no effect since `-or "y"` is always true. Entering any non-y value in mine would make `$confirm -eq "y"` return false